# Nightwatch JS. Running parallel different tests

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I have some tests with tag "parallel".

I want to run it in two browsers parallel, i.e. the first test will start in first browser, and the second will start in second browser simultaneously.

I try to do it this command:

```
npm run nightwatch -- --env default,default --tag parallel
```

but in result, in each browser there is first test from my tag.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I setup my config, added to Environment:
"test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "selenium_port": 4444,
            "selenium_host": "localhost",
            "default_path_prefix": "/wd/hub",
            "silent": true,
            "screenshots": {
                "enabled": true,
                "on_failure": true,
                "on_error": true,
                "path": "tmp_screenshots"
            }
        },

```
    "firefox": {
        "desiredCapabilities": {
            "browserName": "firefox",
            "marionette": true,
            "acceptSslCerts": true,
            "javascriptEnabled": true
        },
        "globals": {
            "type": "firefox",
            "user": "me1",
            "pass": "test"
        }
    },

    "chrome": {
        "desiredCapabilities": {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "chromeOptions": {
                "args": [
                    "disable-web-security",
                    "use-fake-device-for-media-stream",
                    "use-fake-ui-for-media-stream"
                ]
            },
            "acceptSslCerts": true,
            "javascriptEnabled": true
        },
        "globals": {
            "type": "chrome",
            "user": "me1",
            "pass": "test"
        }
    },
```

and when i run execute line below
npm run nightwatch -t tests/google.js -e firefox,chrome
My test starts in two different browsers.